# Windows 10 virtual desktops - preserve taskbar order

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, virtual-desktop

Is there a way to preserve the taskbar order while switching between virtual desktops in Windows 10? The order resets on my PC every time, and that's very annoying.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### New answer for Win11

Use this Windhawk mod from the same author:
https://windhawk.net/mods/virtual-desktop-taskbar-order

Install Windhawk, then install the mod.

### Original answer for Win10

7+ Taskbar Tweaker v5.2 has an option to fix this.

http://rammichael.com/7-taskbar-tweaker-v5-2-with-support-for-windows-10-anniversary-update

Simply install the utility, and change the advanced option 'virtual_desktop_order_fix' from `0` to `1`. (The advanced options are accessible via the context menu on the 7TT icon in the tray.)

Comment: Looks like that as of 5.2.1, this works with a quirk: the pinned icons have "priority" over non pinned icons, so don't mix pinned/non-pinned icons to make this work correctly

Comment: @Erandros the limitation is described [here](http://rammichael.com/7-taskbar-tweaker-v5-2-with-support-for-windows-10-anniversary-update#comment-7189)

Comment: Darn, this doesn't seem to work anymore with v5.7.1 and Windows 10 1803.

Comment: thank you! I wonder why this wouldn't be on by default...

Comment: Awesome solution! , That option is also available with v5.13.

Answer (score 10):

Since I don't have enough reputation (yet), to comment on Cameron's answer above: In addition to ensuring you have the latest version installed (>=v5.2), to access '**Advanced Options**' you have to actually first right-click on the 7TT icon to see it. Then you can tweak the `virtual_desktop_order_fix` option.

Stumped me for a little while because I assumed you could get to it through the regular interface.

Comment: You saved my day! Couldnt find it too! :)

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 5):

Go to Settings--> System --> Multitasking and under 'Virtual desktops' change the option 'On the taskbar, show windows that are open on' to 'All desktops'.

I'm not exactly sure what your problem is as it's very vaguely described in your question, but if it's only showing taskbar items on a certain desktop, this should fix it.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I meant. What I meant is that if I reorder the items, go to a different Virtual Desktop, and then come back, the reordering resets to the previous order (probably the order the programs were opened).

Comment: oh, that's odd. My computer does not display this behavior

Comment: Issue still occurs 2023... The "All desktops" setting is at least a workaround. Not allowed to install 3rd party stuff from unknown source... I am just wondering that MS is not able to solve that issue within almost 8 years.