# How to keep task bar button order fixed in Window 11

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts

I really want to know how to fix the task bar button order,
because I'd like to use the applications in an ordered way.
But in window11 , every time an notification comes, or when
my test finished in Rider, the application icon comes to the
rightest of the task bar,which is very annoying.

***Is there a way for these icons to be fixed where they are, when i first opened it?***

(By which I can just navigate around using Keyboard only,like <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>1,2,3?</kbd>)

---

[Things that I've tried,but not work]

1. turn off the notification in win11
2. adjust task bar settings in win11
3. fix app in the task bar

---

[Ways to reproduce my problem]

1. open apps in an order the way and start a test
   [image: Before Test]
2. switch to another virtual desktop2(by <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow</kbd> )
   [image: Switch to desktop 2 and wait for test to end]
3. after notification order changed
   [image: After Notification]

Comment: My Windows 11 task bar icons are mostly fixed as I also like an orderly way. Mostly means I move the right side system tray icons back to where they belong. So I do not see anything wrong of reordering my icons randomly. What is Rider and what other task bar management Apps might you have. Just to repeat, my order is most repeatable and once or twice a month I fix them up.

Comment: @John See https://www.jetbrains.com/rider/

Comment: Yes, my question was more toward is it interfering with Task Bar settings

Comment: Is pinning the applications to the taskbar to set the order a solution?

Comment: thanks for your reply, but in my case it does not seem to work.
It's my bad for not specifying the procedures.
Seems like that `switching to another virtual desktop ` is the key to reproduce the problem, when without switching,everything works fine .

Comment: @John Thanks for you reply, but looking for Rider's docs seems like a bit overwhelming in my case. I just thought that it might be corrected by some ***easy engineering*** in win11's settings. I'll check that later,when no solutions appears

Comment: Did you try @Paul's answer from Windows 10 virtual desktops - preserve taskbar order: [https://superuser.com/questions/1017188/windows-10-virtual-desktops-preserve-taskbar-order/1124627#1124627](https://superuser.com/questions/1017188/windows-10-virtual-desktops-preserve-taskbar-order/1124627#1124627)

Comment: @XP1 thanks a lot, It worked!  
`Keyboard only mode` -> on in 2024!  
If I turn the system notification of Rider off.(It won't work,when the notification is on.The icon of Rider on the taskbar will blink not matter what i've done to the notification setting...)  
## operation steps
1. Turn off all the notification on WIN11 settings(But it won't work for Rider...)
2. Turn off notification setting in Rider's settings(But Rider's notification will still come...)
3. Install [this] (https://superuser.com/questions/1017188/windows-10-virtual-desktops-preserve-taskbar-order/1124627#1124627)